# XGBoost Feature importance - Gain and Cover are high but Frequency is low

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I have read this question: [How do i interpret the output of XGBoost importance?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12318/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-xgboost-importance) about the three different types of feature importances: frequency (called "weight" in Python XGBoost), gain, and cover.

In my case, I have a feature, Gender, that has a very low importance based on the frequency metric, but is the most important feature by far based on both the gain, and cover metrics.

I know gender should be important for what I'm predicting. If I plot only gender vs. the target, there is a clear correlation. I am not surprised that it's the most important feature. I just want to know why it's not considered an important feature based on the frequency metric.

Answer (score 9):

> I just want to know why it's not considered an important feature based on the frequency metric.

Most likely, the variable *gender* has much smaller number of possible values (often only two: male/female or 0/1, depending on the representation) compared to other predictors in your dataset.

If *gender* is just binary in your case, it means that it can be used at most once in each tree, while, let say, *age* might appear much more often on different levels of the trees.